# Jython execute Python code in Java line by line

Tags: java, jython

I am attempting to compile some Python code, in Java, and store it as a PyCode object. Then, I am trying to execute the compiled code line by line. However, I only seem to be able to run all the code at once. If I compile the code line by line, then execute each line as a separate statement, things like if statements don't work (It throws an exception, saying an indented block of code was expected after the if statement). I am trying to do this, because I want to check the state of a variable after each line is run. After this variable is updated, I want to run some Java code.

Thanks, Rees.

P.S. I am running Jython 2.5.3

Comment: are you simply trying to debug it? Can't you use any kind of IDE with this function?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I am trying to use PythonInterpreter to execute one statement, or one line, one after another. Unfortunately, it doesn't expect a next line after the current one. That means that, if it tries to execute a string like "if a == False:", it throws an error. This is because there isn't any indented code after the if statement, however there is if it waited until the next statement was executed, it would find the code.

Comment: did you try to translate the whole code to java? is there any reason to leave it to python?